# Cannot get a simple XMLHttpRequest to work

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest

I'm struggling to get this to work as part of a larger exercise.

It's pretty simple - a user fills in a form which is sent using an XMLHttpRequest to a processing page. This should return a response below the form.

I had it almost working, but one field wouldn't show... and now nothing. Could this be a cache problem or is a problem with the code.

Here's the form:

```
<div id="miniContact">
<label for="yourName">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="yourName" id="yourName"><br>

<label for="phone">Your Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
<input type="text" name="reqd" id="reqd"><br>

<label for="email">Your Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>

<label for="type">Your vehicle type</label>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type">

<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onclick="ajax_post();"> <br><br>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function ajax_post(){
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "my_parse_file.php";

        var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

        var yourName    = document.getElementById("yourName").value;
        var phone       = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var reg         = document.getElementById("reg").value;
        var srv     = document.getElementById("reqd").value;
        var email       = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var type        = document.getElementById("type").value;



        var vars = "yourName="+yourName+"&phone="+phone+"&reg="+reg+"srv="+service+"email="+email+"&type="+type;


        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = hr.responseText;
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }
    </script>
```

...and the php file (my_parse_file.php):

```
<?php 
echo 'Thank you '. $_POST['yourName'] . ' ' . $_POST['service'] . ', says the PHP file';

    $user_name      = $_POST['yourName'];
    $reg            = $_POST['reg'];
    $email          = $_POST['email'];
    $srv            = $_POST['srv'];
    $phone_number   = $_POST['phone'];
    $vehicle        = $_POST['type'];

?>
```

Comment: If nothing is working anymore then I would recommend you open your browser console and check for errors. Have you checked? If not, check it and let me know if you see any. **Update:** Also I don't see any elements with the `id` of `reg` so that might also be your problem.

Comment: `document.getElementById("reg").value` seems wrong, since there's no element with the ID `reg`.

Comment: You will no doubt see this error in your browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` That would indicate a failure to read the value property, reason being is because it doesn't exist. This will stop the rest of your function from being executed.

Comment: You do not cancel the submit

Comment: @epascarello in the source provided those elements aren't in a `<form>` so no submit would occur.